# Workflow of User Signup View Controllers for iOS App

Tags: ios, authentication, uiviewcontroller

I'm currently designing the signup views for a new user to my app. 
A new user has to fill in both general profile information and tags for a user's interests. I currently have view controllers for both of these screens (for when an existing user modifies their profile), but I need the code for the signup to be slightly different.

What are some smart ways to design the workflow here?

1. I could simply create duplicate view controllers for the profileController and the tagsController, and make small code modifications, but that seems like a lot of duplicate code.
2. Another option is to redesign the view controllers for tags and profile information into views, and have the view controller display these views in turn.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this and what has worked for me is to separate the views and view controllers (so have a profileController & profileView and a tagsController & tagsView). Then in your view controllers you can indicate when instantiating a view controller if this particular instance will be for signup or modifying the current user. Then you can check that flag in the view controller for the specific pieces of the view that you want to change.